# Upload .apk file in google play store as paid and free

Tags: android

How to place an .apk file in google play store as paid app and free app. After placing my app in play store as free then again I tried to upload same .apk file as paid app in play store. But it is not uploading and saying that package is already exist. Please help me.

Comment: You have to change the package name - basically these are seen as two different apps.

Comment: you can not upload more than one app with same package in google play store. You need to change the package name

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `package name` for paid version. Two apps with same package name not possible to upload.

For Example :

1) Free version package name : `com.myapp.free`

2) Paid version package name :  `com.myapp.pro`

Refer [this free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zeptolab.ctrexperiments.ads) and [this paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zeptolab.ctrexperiments.google.paid) app package names.

Comment: This makes sense.  Why would you be able to have an exact same app available for free and at a cost?  They must be different in some way, therefore requiring a different package name.  Although, a case could be made that payment is optional for downloading an app, Google probably did not intend that.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, once you make it as Free. You can't change the settings of the same app to be made as a paid one. It is in their Terms and Condition. You need to repackage as a new one.

More information about this can be found **[here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html)**